# Adding a class to my function

Tags: jquery, css

I am taking a course that requires me to make a "Random Quote Generator".

I am trying to add this class:

```css
div.info p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

to my arrays I've created in my jQuery. I am completely lost. I've tried adding

```js
.addClass(div.info p)
```

to my code, and I think that's how I am supposed to do it, but not sure how.

Here is my JS so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function getQuote() {
    var quotes = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p" ];
    var author = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p" ];

    $.each($('.info'), function(i, element) {
      $(element).html(quotes[randomNum]);
    });

    var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * quotes.length));
    var randomQuote = quotes[randomNum];
    var randomAuthor = author[randomNum];

    $(".quote").text(randomQuote);
    $(".author").text(randomAuthor);
  }

  $(".btn").on("click", getQuote);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of selecting an element, add CSS class selector, for example, *.my-paragraph* and add the desired style, then using jQuery add that class to your paragraphs `.addClass("my-paragraph")`. Assuming you want to add this style to your quotes: `$(".quote").text(randomQuote).addClass("my-paragraph");`.

```js
$("p").addClass("my-paragraph");
```

```css
.my-paragraph {
   color: blue;
   font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>My paragraph</p>
<p>My other paragraph</p>
```

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly, I imported the ajax to my external in codepen.

If I have my array defined as quotes and randomQuotes.

Wouldn't it make sense to do 

$("randomQuote").addClass("div.info p")  ?

Edit: Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: If you are using [.addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) method, you need to use CSS class selector (up here is an example). When your function is going to iterate through arrays, it will automatically add that style with _.addClass_ method.

Comment: That looks like you're editing the HTML using jQuery. Am I correct?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Much appreciated!

Comment: No, you are just adding a style to the generated quotes, which is HTML text. I tested it in your codepen code you mentioned and it works like I said. This is unnecessary and it won't work _$("quotes").addClass("div.info p")_. First, add some class selector to your CSS and change a line in JS like this _$(".quote").text(randomQuote).addClass("some-selector");_

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because you need to generate a new random number every time you attempt to access the arrays - assuming you want a different outcome each time. Try this:

```js
function getQuote() {
  var quotes = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"];
  var author = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"];

  var random = function(max) {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * max));
  }
  
  $.each($('.info'), function(i, element) {
    $(element).html(quotes[random(quotes.length)]);
  });

  var randomQuote = quotes[random(quotes.length)];
  var randomAuthor = author[random(author.length)];

  $(".quote").text(randomQuote);
  $(".author").text(randomAuthor);
  
}

$(".btn").on("click", getQuote);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
<div class="info"></div>

Quote:
<div class="quote"></div>

Author:
<div class="author"></div>

<button class="btn">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Rory thank you so much! That is much appreciated, however here is the link to the project.
https://codepen.io/jsf2008/pen/vZQxPe

I have 12 different objects that eventually I will generate to being 12 different new quotes every single time. The next step is to do that in jQuery. It's just getting the replacement array to be displayed with the same class I'm having an issue with.